# symfony 3.4 Doctrine COUNT

Tags: symfony

this code works well to count how many "2014-01-01 00:00:00" there is in my column "session" but I want the day to be anything not only 01.

```
    class BooknowRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllOrderedByNb() {

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')

                        ->select('COUNT(a)')

                        ->where('a.session = :session')

                        ->setParameter('session', '2014-01-01 00:00:00')

                        ->getQuery()

                        ->getSingleScalarResult();

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "anything"? Why not use another condition then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class BooknowRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllOrderedByNb() {

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->select('COUNT(a)')
            ->where('a.session LIKE :session')
            ->setParameter('session', '%2014-01%')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult()
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: stackoverflow.com/q/56338792/8631622 Please look into this problem. I did everything I could. But I could not solve this problem @stephan.mada

Answer (score 0):

**Several dates**

> but I want the day to be anything not only 01

If I have understood you correctly, your want find count of dates from array. In SQL this is implemented using *WHERE IN* syntax — in Doctrine you are greatly encouraged to use *$qb->expr()->in()* method.

```
$sessions = ['2014-01-01 00:00:00', '2014-01-03 00:00:00'];    
...  

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
...    
$qb->select('COUNT(a)')
   ->where($qb->expr()->in('a.session', ':sessions'))
   ->setParameter('sessions', sessions)
```

Dotrine doc: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods

**Date range**

If you want to get count of rows in month/year you need set a interval until the start of the next month

```
->andWhere('a.session >= :startSession')
->andWhere('a.session < :finishSession')
->setParameter('startSession', '2014-01-01 00:00:00')
->setParameter('finishSession', '2014-02-01 00:00:00')
```